# Should I use "is" or "are" when the subject is a list of percentages before a collective noun?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, collective-nouns, percentages

I am stuck in choosing the correct verb (*is* or *are*) for the following sentence, since *generation* is uncountable (singular agreement) and it is preceded by multiple percentages (plural agreement).

Which one should I use?

> 70, 40, 10, 60, and 10% of the old generation **is/are** selected randomly for the crossover, mutation, swap, reversion, and insertion operators, respectively.

Comment: @Davo mine is a bit more specific in terms of its different percentages.

Comment: No, as stated your question is a duplicate. However, if you are asking whether *multiple* percentages require a different verb, then you should make that clear in the question. It would also help to reference the other (nominated) question and say exactly why it doesn't help.

Comment: Would you say 'Half of the men is bachelors'?

Comment: @AndrewLeach as can be implied, i insist on the particularity of my question, exactly because there are, as you kindly said,  multiple percentages concerning an uncountable noun right after that.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: no i would say half of the men are bachelors, since men can be counted.

Comment: @SajjadSAberi **Edit your question.** Don't imply anything, and don't rely on comments.

Comment: It's certainly a duplicate, and well answered by Matt E. Эллен♦'s answer: << It depends on if the percentage is made up of units (e.g. 10% of people) or is part of a whole (e.g. 10% of the cake). >> and my caveat. Here, 'generation' is a red herring; the referents are people [in the specified generation] (plural verb-form) but a selected portion (so  '70%' as a deleted form of  'a sample consisting of 70%') may be given singular agreement.  I'd say you could use either with other examples, but you mention 5 samples, so a deletion is at best clumsy.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Would you say "70% of the water have been drunk"? So why "70% of that generation have been referred"? Whilst "generation" is not strictly an uncountable noun in the way that water is, we are here only talking about a single generation. I see your point about referents. So my judgement is that either *have* or *has* would work.

Comment: Would you say 'fish and chips are my favourite meal'? Notion agreement doesn't need to correspond exactly to formal agreement (or it wouldn't be a separate concept). With mass nouns, agreement is far simpler because the referent and the noun concerned match. With '35% of Parliament', the referent (MPs in the UK) is covert.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps I voted to close too hastily on this occasion. On reflection, I think the word *respectively* should be ignored when considering numerical agreement. So *this **is** his*, but *this, that and the other **are** his, hers and theirs, respectively*.

Comment: On that basis, I've voted to reopen this question.

Comment: I've edited the title to match the body of your question, and I've also highlighted the point of uncertainty. Please feel free to [edit] it further or to roll back the changes.